# Make text follow a wavy line illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, text-on-path, path-effects

I have used the zigzag option under distort on a line to make a wavy line like this:

[image]

But the path is still a straight line.

How can I get around this, as the end goal is to make some text follow it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After applying the Effect, chose `Object > Expand Appearance` and the effect will be "baked In" making the path actually look like the effect. You can then use the Type On A Path feature to add text.